Textform field validation error message overlapping
When the validation message pops up, it is overlapping with the new text. How do I fix it?

          Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                    width: 320,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      key: const ValueKey('email'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                          return 'Please enter a valid email';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                        labelText: 'Email Address',
                        labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onSaved: (newValue) {
                        _userEmail = newValue!;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 12,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                    width: 320,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      key: const ValueKey('password'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 7) {
                          return 'Password must be atleast 7 characters';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                        labelText: 'Password',
                        labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        ),
                      ),
                      obscureText: true,
                      onSaved: (newValue) {
                        _userPassword = newValue!;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),

My Textformfield is wrapped in a sized box to contain its size. Is it something to do with focusnode? It is also wrapped in a sized box and the textform field section is constrained.
My Textformfield is wrapped in a sized box to contain its size. Is it something to do with focusnode? It is also wrapped in a sized box and the textform field section is constrained.

Add your code snippet for TextFormfileds

Code snippet added.

because you set fix height of the SizedBox that wraps TextFormField. You may remove the height or increase the value of the height

Remove height of textform fileds

Please don't give hight and widht using sized box to textformfield
use contentPadding option for textformfield
final email = TextFormField(
keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
autofocus: false,
initialValue: 'sathyabaman@gmail.com', 
style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, color: Colors.white),
decoration: InputDecoration(
  hintText: 'Email', 
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
  border: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)
  ),
),
)

